# How to convert List<string> to List<int> where empty or null string to be converted as 0 using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

How to convert `List<string> to List<int>` where empty or null string to be converted as 0 using LINQ in C#

Following LINQ statements will convert the `List<sting>` to `List<int>` but do these statements work for above mentioned scenario

```
listofIDs.Select(int.Parse).ToList()

var intList = stringList.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my pitch:

```
        var stringlist = new List<String> { "1", "2", "", null };
        var intList = stringlist.Select(s => { int i; return int.TryParse(s, out i) ? i : 0; }).ToList();
        Debug.Print("{0},{1},{2},{3}", intList[0], intList[1], intList[2], intList[3]);
```

Test output: 1,2,0,0

Not dissimilar to the IsNullOrWhiteSpace suggestion. However, it's safer than just using int.Parse unguarded, which will throw an exception if given invalid input.

A suggestion for you: TDD! Get familiar with one of the many .NET testing frameworks. You can answer questions like yours with another 2-3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
stringList.Select(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? 0 : int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

or you may try using [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) if you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher

```
stringList.Select(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? 0 : int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

For example:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "    ", "", "4" };
List<int> newListOfInt = stringList.Select(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? 
                                                  0 : int.Parse(s)
                                           ).ToList();
```

Comment: in the first line you have a typo. IsNull_Or_Empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listofIDs.Select(id => string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)? 0 : int.Parse(id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var intList = stringList.Select(s => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList()
```